# How can i webscrape depending on 2 user inputs,and storing 4 of the lines as seperate variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have been trying to write a bit of code that will webscrape a website depending on 2 user inputs, one being the gameweek of the match and the other being the home team. I have been struggling to write the code that can narrow down the whole website depending on these 2, and conclude the webscraping once the stadium of the game is found.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

gw=input("Enter the gameweek of the game you would like to attend \\n")
hometeam=input("Enter the name of the home team \\n")

url=requests.get("https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/schedule/Premier-League-Scores-and-Fixtures") 

Fixtures=BeautifulSoup(url.content,"html.parser") 

teams=Fixtures.find('table',id="sched_2023-2024_9_1")
allfixtures=Fixtures.find("th",{"data-stat":"gameweek"})
```

The code i have written is above, and an example of the webscrape data is below:

```
<tr data-row="0"><th scope="row" class="right " data-stat="gameweek">1</th>


<td class="left " data-stat="dayofweek" csk="6">Fri</td>


<td class="left " data-stat="date" csk="20230811"><a href="/en/matches/2023-08-11">2023-08-11</a></td>


<td class="right " data-stat="start_time" csk="20:00:00"><span class="venuetime" data-venue-time-only="1" data-venue-epoch="1691780400" data-venue-time="20:00">20:00</span> <span class="localtime" data-label="your time"></span></td>


<td class="right " data-stat="home_team"><a href="/en/squads/943e8050/Burnley-Stats">Burnley</a></td>


<td class="right " data-stat="home_xg">0.3</td><td class="center " data-stat="score"><a href="/en/matches/3a6836b4/Burnley-Manchester-City-August-11-2023-Premier-League">0–3</a></td>
<td class="right " data-stat="away_xg">1.9</td>


<td class="left " style="font-weight: bold;" data-stat="away_team"><a href="/en/squads/b8fd03ef/Manchester-City-Stats">Manchester City</a></td>


<td class="right " data-stat="attendance" csk="21572">21,572</td><td class="left " data-stat="venue">Turf Moor</td>


<td class="left " data-stat="referee" csk="Craig Pawson2023-08-11">Craig Pawson</td>


<td class="left " data-stat="match_report"><a href="/en/matches/3a6836b4/Burnley-Manchester-City-August-11-2023-Premier-League">Match Report</a></td><td class="left iz" data-stat="notes"></td></tr>
```

I have copied a part of the html where i would like the start of the webscrape to be set by the gameweek that the user inputs, as seen in the first line.

The 4 variables i would like to store are the date of the game from the 3rd line of html, the time of day from the 4th line, the away team from the 6th line and the venue of the match on the 7th line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be reading the HTML table into Pandas dataframe (using `pd.read_html()`) and then query the Dataframe, for example:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/schedule/Premier-League-Scores-and-Fixtures"

df = pd.read_html(url)[0].dropna(how="all")
df["Wk"] = df["Wk"].astype(int)

print(df.query('Wk == 1 and Home == "Arsenal"'))
```

Prints:

```
   Wk  Day        Date   Time     Home   xG Score  xG.1             Away  Attendance             Venue         Referee  Match Report Notes
1   1  Sat  2023-08-12  12:30  Arsenal  0.8   2–1   1.2  Nott'ham Forest     59984.0  Emirates Stadium  Michael Oliver  Match Report   NaN
```